# Usage of ? in native SQL query on jsonb

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

I need to fire a select query against Postgres `jsonb` column:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
 "select * from table where jsonbcol -> 'usernames' ? :un"
).setParameter("un", userName).getResultList()
```

Upon running the Exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterRecognitionException: Mixed parameter strategies - 
use just one of named, positional or JPA-ordinal strategy
```

I tried escaping like `\\?` and `??` but that didn't help.

How to do that call properly?

Comment: I would try `\\??` and `\\?\\?`, but I don't have a setup for it. It would be faster for you to try them and tell us if one of them works.

Comment: `jsonbcol -> 'usernames' \\?\\? :un` works like a charm, if such wording can by applied to this sick c^#p

Comment: @coladict put is as an answer pls, so I can accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper escape sequence makes the query like this:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
 "select * from table where jsonbcol -> 'usernames' \\?\\? :un"
).setParameter("un", userName).getResultList()
```

The backslashes escape hibernate parameter detection, and the two question-marks are the JDBC escape.

Comment: Triple escaping! A record for me :D
One for JDBC, one for Hibernate and the last for Java.

Comment: This is a great answer and solved the issue I was facing. There is some nuance to which question marks should be escaped in jsonb. For example a query using a json path expression such as SELECT * FROM SchemaType s WHERE s.schemadata @? '$.** ? (@.type == "string") ' should NOT escape the question mark within the json path literal '$.** ? (@.type == "string")'  but only at the @? operator.

Comment: @JamesW How did you go about escaping `@?`, I tried `@\\?\\?` but that gives error

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative solution that can turn out to be an elegant workaround. Postgres operator `?` is based on the `jsonb_exists()` function, so instead of

```
where jsonbcol -> 'usernames' \\?\\? :un
```

you can use

```
where jsonb_exists(jsonbcol -> 'usernames', :un)
```

Comment: See also the result from this query: SELECT * FROM pg_operator WHERE oprname = '?';

Comment: You can use the functions, but they don't benefit from indexes, if you create any.

Comment: It worked for me with "jsonb_exists" function but not working with " \\?\\? " escape character

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/statement.html) says:

> In JDBC, the question mark (`?`) is the placeholder for the positional parameters of a `PreparedStatement`. There are, however, a number of PostgreSQL operators that contain a question mark. To keep such question marks in a SQL statement from being interpreted as positional parameters, use two question marks (`??`) as escape sequence.