# Spring Boot - Entity Manager - Native query for handling jsonb operators

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, nativequery

I am using spring boot and jpa to execute native queries. One of my column is jsonb and I need to use json operator "?|" which tries to see if any value exist in array. It fails with "ordinal parameter not bound: 1"

This is what I am trying to execute:

`query = "select id from test where array['partner'] @> facet_names and ( values->'partner' is null or (values->'partner'->>'operator'='IN' and values->'partner'->'values' ?| array['partner.com']) ) order by rank limit 1;"`

`this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList()`

I got this error:
`Ordinal parameter not bound : 1`

And I know it is because of operator "?" but how do I resolve this?

I tried escaping operator "?" using \ and then I got a different error
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.`

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Usage of ? in native SQL query on jsonb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600968/usage-of-in-native-sql-query-on-jsonb) I have faced with similar issue while using `@?` operator, however replacing it with `@\\?\\?` helped