# How to create index on deeply nested jsonb attribute in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a table called **orders** that contains a column called **data**, whose data type is **jsonb**, and it looks like this

```
"data": [
  "items": [
   {"name": "Peter"},
   {"name": "John"}
  ]
]
```

This is the query to retrieve a list of unique names:

```
    SELECT distinct NameList->'name' AS uniqueNames
FROM orders
         CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) itemsData
         CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(itemsData->'items') NameList
WHERE NameList != '[]'
```

Here, **data** have a lot of other informations, but I'm interested in **items**. Therefore, How do I create an index on **NameList != '[]'** ?

Comment: No, that's an alias created in this query, it's not the data. You need an index on "data", see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING

Comment: That is not a valid format for a json(b) document.

Comment: No index can help you with that query. You should change the data model, split the data into several related tables and avoid JSON. Then the solution would be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for performance, on PostgreSQL 12+ [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) should be faster than that even without index support. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/P_JwENMg)

```sql
select distinct jsonb_path_query(data,'$.data[*].items[*].name') 
from orders 
where data @? '$.data[*].items[*].name';
```

The [`@?` "path-exists" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) does the same thing you tried to do: it checks if there are any `name`s under that path. The key difference is it does that in a single `jsonpath` expression, and thanks to `[*]` array accessor, it doesn't need to unnest any layers
or use set-returning functions at all.

You can improve its performance by letting an index narrow down which rows don't need to be checked, re-using the condition from the `where` above:

```sql
create index on orders((data @? '$.data[*].items[*].name'));
```

---

There are a few issues with your question

1. The `jsonb` value you presented isn't formatted right. `data` is a key, so it needs to be in an object. I'm guessing its value is an array, as indicated by square brackets it contains and the fact you're calling `jsonb_array_elements()` on it. `items` is also a key, so it needs to be in an object, as an element of the `data` array. So you're missing one pair of outer curly brackets, and another one around `items`:

   ```
   {   "data": [
           {   "items": [
                   {   "name": "Peter"},
                   {   "name": "John" }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. The query isn't syntactically or logically valid:

   1. You aliased result sets from `jsonb_array_elements()` without naming their fields/columns, so your references are to their whole records instead of what's in them:

      ```sql
      CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) itemsData
      CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(itemsData->'items') NameList
      ```

      Define a name for the result set *and* its field name to be able to use it like that:

      ```
      CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) AS elements1(itemsData)
      CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(itemsData->'items') AS elements2(NameList)
      ```
   2. `NameList != '[]'` would work if you checked an empty `jsonb` array, but you've just used a function to open it up and explode into individual elements; before the fix above, `NameList` is a record holding a single array element. After the fix, it's the array element. I think `(itemsData->'items')` is the array you want to check

      ```
      CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) AS elements1(itemsData)
      CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(itemsData->'items') AS elements2(NameList)
      WHERE (itemsData->'items') != '[]'
      ```

      But the condition isn't really helpful: if that array's empty, the function won't produce anything anyways, so there's no need to filter it out. It also can't be used to estimate which rows of the table can be skipped, because of how deep down into each row it has to reach in order to establish that and because that's carried out with set-returning functions, you can't build an expression index that would correspond to this condition (see below).
3. `jsonb_array_elements()` is a set-returning function, so it can't be used in [an expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html):

   ```
   ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in index expressions
   ```

   Still, since your array check can be fixed, a similar fix can be used to give you a somewhat usable index:

   ```sql
   create index on orders((data->'data')) 
   where (jsonb_array_length(data->'data')>0);
   ```

   That would maybe help if your `data` was sometimes empty and you frequently checked its contents but what you seem to worry about is an `items` list inside that, which this won't really help with.

That being said, [normalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Example_of_a_step-by-step_normalization) structure would be far easier to index and query, and way lighter and faster at both.

Comment: Zegarek Thank you so much. Could you please explain what does @? mean in this context? 

`where data @? '$.data[*].items[*].name';`

I have run into an exception due that operator. I tried to escape it but, it still failing . This exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot mix parameter styles between JDBC-style, ordinal and named in the same query`

Comment: It means the same thing you tried to specify: it checks if there are any names under that path. The difference is it does that in a single `jsonpath` expression, and thanks to being able to use `[*]` array accessor, it doesn't need set-returning functions, or unnesting each layer at all. What means of escaping the operator have you tried so far and how did the error message change?

Comment: This is how tried escape so JDBC does not complains, but it's still failing: using `@??`

Comment: The issue is raising due to question mark I guess. Is there any operator I can use instead of @? to achieve same results? I'm still digging into the docs.

Comment: There's a [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function that does the same thing but indexes are tied to operator classes, so switching from the operator to the function will disable index support.

Comment: On second thought, it shouldn't necessarily matter here because that's actually a boolean expression index, which you reuse verbatim in both places anyways.

Comment: I was able to fix this following by escaping it like so: `@\\?\\?`. I got the answer from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600968/usage-of-in-native-sql-query-on-jsonb